Blender selects two armatures together. what to do?
When I press A to select an armature, it selects both! How to solve?


I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

You probably have 2 armatures selected, go back to Object mode, select one armature only, then switch to Pose mode

I managed to solve it, thank you very much

Hi, welcome to BSE! This site is a bit special, in being a Q&A where we need clear questions and answers both of good quality. Please do not use the question field to insert comments or "thanks i solved it". Instead, comments should remain in the comments section, and answers should be posted, nicely elaborated, in the comments section. See the FAQ articles for more: Can I answer my own question and How do I write a good answer?.

A is the shortcut to select everything visible in the context. If you are in object mode, it selects all objects. If you are in edit mode, it selects everything in that context. The key here is "everything", not "a specific thing".
In your first screenshot, we can see that you are in pose mode on two objects. It's visible in the viewport by the fact that both your armatures' bones are displayed as being posable. Though that could also be that you actually have your two characters armatures into one, but the outliner make it obvious those are indeed two separated armatures currently in Pose Mode:

To fix this, Tab into object mode, select only one of the objects, and Tab back into Pose Mode. Or, while in pose mode, go in the outliner and click the white armature icon on the left side of the armature to make it the only one being in pose mode.
